# How to get songs remaining and total duration time from media player?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

friends, I don't know how to get songs remaining and total duration from the media player. In my code, I want to get songs total duration and remaining duration and show in text view with proper time formatting:

```
 updateseekbar=new Thread(){

                     @Override public  void run(){
                  int totalduration=mediaPlayer.getDuration();
                  int currnetpostion=0;




                  while (currnetpostion<totalduration){
                      try{
                     sleep(500);
                     currnetpostion=mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                     seekBar.setProgress(currnetpostion);



                      }catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                      }

                  }
            }
        };
```

What do I need to do in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can acheive this by substracting current duration from total duration, In your code I can see you have both Total and current duration.

```
remainingDuration  = totalduration -   currnetpostion=mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
```

May be work your case

Answer (score 1):

As i see in your code....

totalduration= the total time of the song;

but if you want to current position of the media player. You have to put your code inside the runnable and update the current position at every second....

```
 final Handler handler=new Handler();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int duration=mediaplayer.getcurrentPosition();
            //and update your seekbar from handler
            //change your int to time format...
            String time = String.format("%02d:%02d ", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration) -
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration)));
             updateseekbar();
            handler.postDelayed(this,1000);
        }
    });
```

if you are not getting it ask this again